# JSDoc via npm not parsing any comments

Tags: node.js, git, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I've installed JSDoc and JSDoc 3 Tool from npm.

```
npm install git+https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc.git
sudo apt-get install jsdoc-toolkit
```

The software installed successfully, executed the command (*jsdoc -r=doc file.js*), and the folder with files was generated.

However, the mark-up is ignored and the index.html links only to the following path, describing the *global* class:

```
/docs/symbols/_global_.html
```

Where have I strayed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This had to do with permissions on the server.